# PaginateViewHelper redirect to request page

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, flow-framework

I'm using `TYPO3\Fluid\ViewHelpers\PaginateViewHelper` in my index action which listing some items. Each item has actions which are done on the fly, so after action is called and processed it's back to the index action.

```
public function deleteAction(Item $item) {
    $this->itemService->remove($item);
    $this->redirect('index');
}
```

Unfortunately in this case I'm getting redirected to the first page of index. Is there possibility to redirect to the page where I'm triggering delete action? Can I also obtain arguments of subrequest send to `PaginateController`?

I know I can use AJAX call instead or write my own pagination, but I'd like to use existing solution if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the GET Parameters you can use addQueryString="1" in the LinkViewHelper... maybe this is already enough to keep the current page when using redirect() in the controller.

Otherwise you can use the UriBuilder of the controller to generate a URI including the desired page in your pagination and other parameters and then use the function redirectToUri() to redirect the user to the desired URI.

https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_mvc_1_1_web_1_1_routing_1_1_uri_builder.html

Comment: In fact it's adding query parameter, but it's not delivered to my action. The only place where I see page from the URL is `HttpRequest` (`$this->httpRequest`), but I have to parse it manually and it's not satisfying me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
$referringRequest = $this->request->getReferringRequest();
if ($referringRequest !== null) {
    $this->redirectToRequest($referringRequest);
}
```

This only works, if the referring request is sent with the original request, which is the case for Fluid Forms, which you should use for unsafe requests (POST, PUT, DELETE).